# Why are Jews always targets?

Tags: history, anti-semitism

Throughout history Jews have been targets and scapegoats for people's stupidity, crimes and failure. Why? What makes this group so much more susceptible to racism and hatred?

Comment: http://www.aish.com/sem/wtj/82875402.html  http://www.amazon.com/Why-Jews-The-Reason-Antisemitism/dp/0743246209

Answer (score 0):

According to Jewish philosophy and mysticism, man is a dual creature, combining both a noble, divine, altruistic drive as well as a base, selfish, physical one. The Jewish people were chosen to be a "light onto the nations" to guide them toward the subservience of the base drives to to divine ones.  As such, men who chose to guide themselves by their base, corporeal drives resent and hate the Jews and what they represent. ("Conscience is a Jewish invention, it is a blemish like circumcision." - Rauschning, Hitler Speaks, p. 220)

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate. You might consider moving this (very interesting) answer over to the [older question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18553/5323), where all the other answers can be found