# Jewish nachas (satisfaction)

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, blessing, yiddish, minhagim

What is the source of the phrase "a sach yiddishe nachas" ?

Why specify 'jewish' ?

Comment: As Avrohom Yitzchok in his answer points out, we want Yiddische nachas. The Lubavitcher Rebbe (Igros Kodesh,  ד (תשי"א)) wrote for example that we want to see our childeren educated the Jewish way. With Torah etc... That is why we say Yiddishe Nachas.

Comment: I just saw https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75427/why-do-we-consider-eisavs-nachas-goyish-if-eisav-was-a-jew which looks like the original - this is therefore a dupe.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I'm looking for a source. That doesn't address it.

Answer (score 3):

[Beraishis 36 (13)](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8231)
shows that Nachas was a grandson of Eisav and son of Reuel.

יג  וְאֵלֶּה בְּנֵי רְעוּאֵל נַחַת וָזֶרַח שַׁמָּה וּמִזָּה אֵלֶּה הָיוּ בְּנֵי בָשְׂמַת אֵשֶׁת עֵשָֽׂו:

13 And these are the sons of Reuel: Nahath, Zerah, Shammah, and Mizzah. These are the sons of Basemath, the wife of Esau.

While we wish for nachas, we don't want a grandson of Eisav and so we want “yiddishe nachas”.

Comment: Do you know that this is the reason?

Comment: Is this your own chiddush, because i LOVE it!

Comment: @magicker72 Do I "know"? That is what I have been told many times and it seems reasonable. But I have not seen it quoted anywhere. Have lots of yiddishe nachas!!