# Egyptian enslavement of the Jews - Antisemitism?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, egypt, parashas-shemos, anti-semitism

Apologies in advance if this is too vague of a question, but I really wonder what other people think about this, especially since the story is coming up in a couple of weeks.

I was recently reading a book on the history of Antisemitism, and the first examples of antisemitism were from as early as 500BCE.

I was thinking that the first example would be the story of Shiabud Mitzrayim, or the Egyptians enslaving us. So my question is: When the Egyptians enslaved us, as told in the beginning of Sefer Shemos, was that an Antisemitic act or was it a reasonable political move (or something else entirely)?

In order to define this a little better, let's use the definition of Antisemitism as:

(actions resulting from) prejudice (preconceived opinion that is not based on reason or actual experience) against Jews. This definition is culled from various Internet definitions.

Thanks!

Edit: Kudos to sabbahillel for bringing Rav Hirsch's opinion, what about other Mefarshim?

Comment: If a wicked king arose and (chas veshalom) said, "Black people are becoming too great. We'll enslave them all and keep their numbers down by killing their newborns." would we not consider them prejudice against people who have black skin? I don't think we'd say that he was trying to keep their numbers down because he saw them as a threat to his sovereignty.

Comment: Not if prejudice is a preconceived opinion that is not based on reason or actual experience.  In this case, it could be easily argued that it was a reasonable measure, and many details of the story would justify this, such as if the Egyptians killed their own children too in http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/1.22#e0n7

Answer (score 4):

Rav Hirsch explains that the *new king* carefully and gradually stirred up anti-Semitism in order to drive down the Israelites because they were a single group or *caste* within the society. All the other elements within the society were divided so that only the Jews could have stood up and resisted the government.

[Shmos 1:8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9862#v=8&showrashi=true)

> A new king arose over Egypt, who did not know about Joseph.

Rav Hirsch says that this was an overthrow of the kingdom and a new dynasty took over.

> וַיָּ֥קָם מֶֽלֶךְ־חָדָ֖שׁ עַל by no means designates an ordinary
>   lawful change of dynasty. קום על is always an overthrow by force.

The Egyptians were subjugated and divided into the different groups so that the invaders were able to control them. The Israelites were unified and could have served as a focus of resistance since the Egyptians still remembered how Yosef had saved them. Thus, the *new king* carefully built up resentment against them and began forcing them into the position of *enemy of society* and the lowest of the low (as slaves) so that there would be someone for all the other groups to look down upon.

> Note in general: (a) this first anti-semitism was not brought about by
>   anything the Jews had done. Pharaoh could not bring any accusation
>   against them, otherwise he would not have been driven to act against
>   them covertly, בחכמה (verse 10); (b) this first רשעה was engineered
>   from above, did not spring from the people. They were incited from
>   above, Jew-hatred was a political measure which the new dynasty used
>   to strengthen their own position of force and violence. There is
>   little new under the sun and historical events at large are as old as
>   history itself. Whenever a tyrant wished to opress a people, he liked
>   to give them a lower class whom they could opress, and thus be
>   indemnified for his own oppression.
>   Many of the Jew-laws of the Middle Ages and later have to thank this
>   policy for their origin. Similar considerations may have guided this
>   first instigator of the first Jew-Laws. He wanted to compensate the
>   Egyptian people whom he held in oppresive subjection by creating for
>   their benefit a caste of pariahs on which every other caste could look
>   down with contempt and in comparison imagine himself a free man.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your definition of AS as "*opinion that is **not based on reason** or actual experience*", I feel that it is important to differentiate between the Egyptian people and Egyptian rulers.

Some suggest that Par'oh had a vast knowledge of Kabbalah and took measures **to systematically weaken and destroy the Jewish nation**, and thus, he was acting against the Jewish people based on Kabbalah.  It is unclear as to whether he had Antisemitic intentions, but likely he had some Kabbalistic motivation to do so, and would then not be qualified as an anti-Semite by the above definition.

However, the rest of the Egyptian people simply acted based on what Par'oh had told them without thinking further about it, and despite them following their ruler, I would suggest that this would qualify as AS.

---

General Notes:

1) To a bigger discussion, I'm very stumbled by the dilemma of the Evil - as we see, many key characters of the Torah were intrinsically good or bad - Moses, Yizhok, Yaakov were born good, Ishmael, Eisov, Amolek etc were born bad.
So one who's born bad with a mission of doing bad - is he doing a Mitzvah (as commanded) or a transgression? I don't really know. If they weren't bad, we wouldn't know how good are the good guys (that's us).

2) When reading the passages of Zohar and Ariz"l explaining their wicked intentions I wonder - did they spend their entire lives in ס"א's Beis Midrash studying this stuff in parallel to our forefathers learning Torah, or it came to them naturally?

Comment: What does ס"א mean?

Comment: ס"א, סיטרא אחרא  The "Other Side" - the "evil" one

Comment: The site is meant for English speakers. Non English terms should preferably be translated in the post, or a link could be provided to an explanation.

Comment: "and took measures to systematically weaken and destroy the Jewish nation. So that does not fit your definition." Why doesn't that fit the definition? Maybe he wanted to weaken and destroy the Jewish nation because he was an anti semite.

Comment: I don't see any source for what you are suggesting. Is there somewhere in the Zohar or Arizal that I could find this?

Comment: Please somebody, help me to find the Pshat Meforshim that wrote that the wicked listed in my answer knew the Kavonos of the forefathers - Yaacov, Yossef, Moses  and acted to prevent the Jews from reaching our goals.

Comment: @mevaqesh I tried to answer according to sabba's definition of anti-semitism. I did not write a general answer about Pharaoh being AS. I.E the Gemoro says Halokho **Eisov hates Yaakov - does it make Eisov AS**? I don't know.

Comment: @AlBerko Obviously you should use the OP's definition of the term, to answer his question. That being said, I don't see how any of this addresses any definition of anti-semitism. It says _what_ Pharaoh did. (tried to weaken the Jewish nation) || The question is _why_ he did it. Was it out of pure hatred, or out of pragmatism, or something else?

Comment: @AlBerko BTW the gemara never says esav sone lyaakov. Almost all texts of those Midrashim that do say this, say הלא בידוע שעשו שונא ליעקב, not halakha byadua. See here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64487/8775.

Comment: e.g. how did Bolok know that Hashem gets angry one special moment a day? How did Lovon know that the Geulah depends on order which Yaakov marryied the sisters (Yaakov said למה רימיתני)?

Comment: @AlBerko Huh? Are you talking to me? If so, WHY CANT YOU JUST PING ME WITH A @? It is very simple, and makes communication much much easier. || Regarding Balak, that is just a Midrash; not peshat. Regarding Lavan, I am not familiar with any such Midrash, I assume it is in some mystical work. It too certainly isnt peshat. || Let's not get sidetracked from the main point, which is that regardless, this isn't an answer.

Comment: While I hate to get sidetracked from the fact that this still isn't an answer, I will note that there is no indication from the Torah that Moses, Yizhok, and Yaakov were born good, or that Ishmael, Eisov, or Amolek were born bad. In fact, according to peshat, Yishmael and Esav werent even so bad. At most one could infer this from the obligation to destroy Amalek, but that is debatable...|| What does this entire point have to do with the post? It is just a distraction.

Comment: @mevaqesh I am so with you. Please excuse me, I'm so bad at Peshat. Don't ask me where in Peshat it says so. I don't know, I could find clues, but you will not agree. I'm from a different school. I would love if you could help me to back my ideas up and show examples from the Peshat that agree with my approach. You give us the Meforshim that say (like the Midrash on התרוצצו בנים בקרבה) that Eisov was bad from the womb and Yaakov the opposite.

Comment: @Al why not just ask a separate question whether there is an indication that some people are born better than others, or whether there is evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @mevaqesh You certainly can. For me this is not a question, it is a fact (e.g. Moses was born circumcised - התמלא הבית אורה).

Comment: Again your "general notes" number one seems totally out of place in this post. Rather than asking it here, in an answer, or even asking me in comments to research your ideas, posting it as a question would probably be better.